# I want to redirect website visitor from "expl.com/... "to "expl.com/index.php/..."

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is my domain http://cdtr.cf  it lands on index.php
Where I wrote some code which pulls the URL from URL box and trim its suffix  to identify visitor's identity.
**The Problem is when someone opening `http://cdtr.cf/....` it shows error 404 page not found**

while just `http://cdtr.cd/`  is working fine. All I need is When someone visit with `http://cdtr.cf/....` they must be redirected to `index.php` and their request should be processed like `http://cdtr.cf/index.php/....`.
I want to keep the suffix anyhow for some purpose :-`http://cdtr.cf/suffix`.
It will be great if all this happen without any visible change in URL box.

Thanks in advance.

```php
    $link= (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=== 'on'? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
    echo $link;  //It is working fine on localhost but not when i put it live
```

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable. It is missing a very important part though: the code. Could you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57670333/edit) and add the code as formatted text (*not* as an image)?

Comment: Seems like some rewriting rules get applied. Those rules are the code @LaurenzAlbe refers to. You will need to find out those rules.

Comment: I edited the question and need help,  plz @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: @arkascha please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the rest of the url as per your requirement

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $link = ltrim($link, '/');

//if you want you can trim last / too using $link = rtrim($link, '/');
?>
```

If you want to get middle stuff like this yoursite.com/stuffs/removedthis

then you have to use below code

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$link = explode('/', $link);

echo $a = $link[1];
?>
```

Second example:

```
$link = "example.com/stuff/removethis/....blah";
$link = explode('/', $link);
echo $a = $link[1];
```